# Xampp remote access - PHP Json

Tags: php, json, apache, xampp

i installed XAMPP on my laptop. I registered with dyndns my public ip address. I have a script in PHP that returns a json file. If I write both the local url (192.168.1.102:80 ...) or public url on the address bar of the target php file, the browser replies with json files...so all ok.
If I use the php file_get_contents and pass as a parameter the same local url, it work...while, if I use the remote address, the function replies that can not find the file. Why? I use xampp. It could be a needed configuration problem xampp or apache ? Help me I'm going crazy.

Comment: maybe a typo or some firewall setting?! can't say much, because I can't see your code.

Answer (score 0):

file that you call from browser address bar is: http://www.demostudio.it/attempt.php
and my code is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo file_get_contents("demostudio.ns0.it:8447/wsServerPc.php");
die();
?>
```

but if you copy and paste in browser address bar: demostudio.ns0.it:8447/wsServerPc.php you see the correct response [{"indice":"-1"}]

why?